# Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited, cannot re-build android project

Tags: java, android, build, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I was programming an Android application when suddenly it was unable to resolve symbol R in my MainActivity. I have had this issue before and it is usually fixed by going to tools->android->syncProjectWithGradleFiles but this did not work. Instead when I attempt to do this it takes me to my AndroidManifest.xml file and gives me the message: "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited" shown below[image]
Furthermore, these errors are displayed below:

[image]
These errors specify that: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon'). which is part of a service I recently tried to add. So I tried deleting the service text here; however whenever I delete the service text, it keeps being re-added to the .xml file whenever I attempt to sync the projects with gradle files again. I have re-built the project and cleaned the project both returning the same errors... Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Check the imported R class if it matches your project not the android.R one.

Comment: just clean up the code

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because you are trying to modify the *wrong version* of AndroidManifest. Android Studio shows you the file located in the build folder when it finds errors. Open app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and modify it.

Answer (score 4):

I had encounter this when I putted 0 value in the screenOrientation attribute and it solved just after I deleted the file in the path

```
...path_to_modoule\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug.AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the affected code and clean the project one or two times and restart Android Studio. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you have filenames that are not accepted by Studio. For example, a file named 001.jpg will throw that error because files cannot start with numbers.
Check if you renamed some file that once belonged to Build and check all the files you added.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after probably deleting by mistake some files from the SDK. I removed Android SDK Build Tools and reinstalled them and the problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

i was solving this problem
step 1:

First remove a android:icon="@drawable/ic_app" and  android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_app" .

step 2:

edit or add android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"

Comment: Just Delete the file please and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I only closed AndroidManifest and opened it again and so I edited acording to which the error log showed.
This problem happens because (for some reason) you have debug/AndroidManifest.xml opened instead of main/AndroidManifest.xml. Just close the debug one and open the main one.