# Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited

Tags: android

The message in my R.java "File under the build folder are generated and should not be edited" ,my code was disappear when I finished and build my program.

And when I open another project,having same problem. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "disappear"? You code was deleted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited, cannot re-build android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389276/files-under-the-build-folder-are-generated-and-should-not-be-edited-cannot-re-b)

Comment: Yes, my code was deleted.