# Modifying a .html file in android studio

Tags: android, html, android-studio

I am modifying this .html file in my assets folder but then when I save it and re run it goes back to its original code ? does anyone know what the issue could be ? 
it is the consentForm.html from this (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-consent-sdk-android)
"files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited."
but according to docs (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#collect_consent) it could be edited
[image]

[image]

Comment: check this-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389276/files-under-the-build-folder-are-generated-and-should-not-be-edited-cannot-re-b

Comment: checked it out but it didn't help me , only was referring to android.xml , in my case i can only find 1 .html file and thats the one that says shouldn't be edited and reverts back to its original text

Comment: figured it out, just copied and pasted the .html file into the assets folder