# AAPT: error: '' is incompatible with attribute allowBackup (attr) boolean

Tags: android, android-activity

this is my code
with the following error how can i fix it ??
(AAPT: error: '' is incompatible with attribute allowBackup (attr) boolean.)
and i have message that say (files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.brokersystem"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="30" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup=""
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BrokerSystem" >
        <activity android:name="com.example.brokersystem.completTrans" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brokersystem.terms1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_terms1"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.BrokerSystem.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.brokersystem.forgPass" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.brokersystem.singUp" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.brokersystem.welcom" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />"
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.brokersystem.MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and it worked for me

try to delete:
`android:fullBackupContent=""` in `AndroidManifest.xml` and let the

`android:allowBackup="true"` get warning.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `allowBackup` should have a boolean value inside it, either `true` or `false`. Set it to which you prefer and the error should disappear.

```xml
android:allowBackup="true"

android:allowBackup="false"
```

Source: [allowBackup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#allowBackup) documentation.

Comment: I had try but it did not work  (files under the "build" folder are generated and should not be edited) this message appear above the code on the bar tools

Comment: Here's another issue that might help you. [Files under the build folder...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389276/files-under-the-build-folder-are-generated-and-should-not-be-edited-cannot-re-b)

Comment: what happen with me now *-* my android studio suddenly stopped and show ( android studio and plugin update available: component: android emulator)

Comment: I cant do any thing, I try to uninstall the program and reinstall it, but the same problem appear

Comment: Updating your src manifest.xml file should not break the application, if that is the case I suspect you've changed something you should not have changed like your files in the build folder, as the message says those a generated and SHOULD NOT be changed. Only change the files in your src folder.

Comment: how can i send pic i want you to see the problem, i can not send it here